# pyrogram bot не видит сообщения пользователей

Tags: pyrogram

В pyrogram не эксперт и в интернете не могу найти ответы на свои вопрос.
Один из них в заголовке этой темы.
Собственно создал бота, запустил. Если я пишу боту сообщения со своего аккаунта, то сообщения бот видит, а если боту пишет сообщения другой пользователь то ничего не происходит. Помогите пожалуйста)

Answer (score 0):

В общем. Создал нового бота на другом аккаунте телеграма, соответственно получил новые api id и api hash и все заработало.
Проблема скорее всего заключается в том, что нельзя админить 2 ботов одновременно. У меня в работе на аккаунте был уже 1 бот и я хотел запустить второго.

Answer (score 0):

На api id и api hash работают юзерботы, в основном на pyrogram. На api больше 1 юзербота и не запустить. Если речь о ботах, работающих на токене, то на 1 аккаунт можно повесить до 20 ботов

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/845625)